How to initialize a service bean with authenticated user info
I have a service that is tightly coupled with the currently authenticated user. It should receive a userId from a higher context (Controller) as an argument in one way or another. The service cannot access the userId from any globally available 'auth' context, it has to be received as an argument.
The service also needs to be a bean (@Service), thus it should be auto-initialized by Spring.
One way to achieve that is the following:

Initialize the service without userId
Then pass userId to every method that is called on the service:

@Service
class MyService
  public void method1(int userId) {
    // do something with userId
  }

  public void method2(int userId) {
    // do something with userId
  }
end

// Usage
myService = new MyService(); // This is done by Spring (with no problem).
myService.method1(getUserIdFromAnyAuthContext())
myService.method2(getUserIdFromAnyAuthContext())

The way I would like my service to work (if it wasn't a bean) is the following:
@Service
class MyService
  private int currentUserId;

  public MyService(int currentUserId) {
    this.currentUserId = currentUserId;
  }

  public void method1() {
    // do something with currentUserId
  }

  public void method2() {
    // do something with currentUserId
  }
end

// Usage
myService = new MyService(getUserIdFromAnyAuthContext()); // I want Spring to be able to do it and have MyService as a bean.
myService.method1()
myService.method2()

The above example shows how I would do it if it wasn't a bean. The point is to not pass userId to every method. It should be injected into the service somehow on each request, but at the same time it should be as if I passed it a standard Java way, so it can be tested independently from the external context.
How to have a service as a bean and initialize it with 'auth' data?
In the case it matters (responding to @Anish B.
comment): I'm going to use Spring Security as an Auth provider. But please note, the service itself can't access any globally available 'auth' context, it should be independent from the external context.

Have you implemented spring security in your project?

@anish-b  Yes I'm going to use spring security. But please note, the service itself can't access any globally available 'auth' context.

How are you going to change the value of the currentUserId field, given that the MyService constructor will only be executed once during the entire lifetime of your application?

@AndreySmelik
In Spring there are per-request beans exist https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-scopes.html#beans-factory-scopes-request
Anyway, my example shows how I would do it if it wasn't a bean.

Then what's stopping you from passing Principal to your service?

@AndreySmelik  At this moment it is probably because I have no idea what you are talking about ) Can you please post an answer with examples?

Spring Security creates an Authentication bean that has information about the current user. If you want to get rid of the dependency on Spring Security, just use the Principal interface that Authentication extends.

Spring Security creates an Authentication bean that has information about the current user. If you want to get rid of the dependency on Spring Security, just use the Principal interface, which is the parent of Authentication.
@Service
class MyService
 
  private final Principal principal;

  public MyService(Principal principal) {
    this.principal = principal;
  }
}

